# Will this chained association cause a performance issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the Message model, I have this function:

```
  def set_phone_number_for_customer!
    unless self.customer.phone_number
      self.customer.set_phone_number
      self.customer.increment_customer_counter
      if self.customer.save
        self.customer.buy_another_phone_number
      end
    end
  end

customers has_many messages
messages have_one customer
customers have_one phone_number
phone_numbers have_many customers
```

this method gets called as a before_save on each Message. I'm worried that doing a chained association like "unless self.customer.phone_number" will cause a performance issue since message creation is the most common action on my app. Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm looking for? I thought maybe I can directly associate phone_number with message but when the message is about to be created, we don't know whether it has an associated phone_number yet (that's the point of that method).

thanks!

Comment: why does your message model care about setting phone numbers on a customer? It seems like the main issue here is that you need to revise the responsibilities of the classes. also, fwiw, there are predicate methods that wrap properties in active record, so you can just do `customer.phone_number?` and that will provide you a true or false instead of a potential value that acts false, but isn't.

Comment: @JedSchneider you should post that as answer, as it's at least 50% of the answer.

Comment: @JedSchneider we do that in message since we need to set a phone number on a customer only when that customer creates their first message

Comment: @JedSchneider also using customer.phone_number? did not work since phone_number is an associated model, not a column on customer.